# Vue/Vite config for multipage app with multiple entry/output files

Tags: vue.js, vite

I need to configure Vue/Vite to accept multiple input files and generate one output bundle for each input file. Each bundle is essentially a different routes and views that use the same components, styles, data models, support services (eg api, auth) etc.

My directly is structured thus:

```
/
/src
>>> customer portal
/src/portal/
/src/portal/index.html
/src/portal/app.vue

>>> admin dashboard
/src/admin/
/src/admin/index.html
/src/admin/app.vue
/src/admin/app.js
```

[According to the docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app), I should be able to view `localhost:8000/portal` or `localhost:8000/admin` and I should see the bundle ... but I don't. I get a 404.

From console:

```
>>> request
GET /portal/# HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000 
>>> response
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

According to the docs this simple nesting should serve on dev fine as a nested path and I shouldn't need to do anything with vite.config.js.

Package.json is:

```
"vue": "^2.6.11"
"vue-router": "^3.5.1"
"vuex": "^3.6.2"
"vite": "^2.3.4"
"vite-plugin-pug": "^0.3.0"
"vite-plugin-vue2": "^1.5.1"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I have similar issue, I need to get from my 2 inputs only 2 output files, without vendor

Comment: No, I haven't yet fixed it. I'm still working on the project, this issue is sidelined for now. Will post back if/when I have a solution. I want something more elegant that has been previously suggested however.

Comment: More than one year later, did you solve this? I am interested as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74288329/vue-3-multipage-app-with-several-html-entries?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

can you try redirect root of your project by

```
const root = resolve(__dirname, 'src');
// once root been changed, the outDir changes too
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

export default defineConfig({
  root,
  ...
  build: {
    outDir,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
         'name': resolve(root, name, 'index.html')
         ...
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [react(), vue()]
})
```

I thought your root is at `/` but mulitple entries is at `/src`,

it should be ok if you try `localhost:3000/src/portal/`