# Vue 3 multipage app with several html entries

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm using Vue3 and Vite
I want to have some of my pages to have different html file as an entry.

for my entire app

```
index.html
index.js
```

but for routes

/product1

```
product1.html
index.js
```

/product2

```
product2.html
index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

This https://github.com/chriscalo/vite-multipage worked well for me.

It adds the different entry points to the build roll-up.

What is nice about it for me, is I can reuse my common components in different apps.